# How to align sprites of smaller sizes to a moving gameobject sprite?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I used to have a game object used as a sword with sprites with a specific size, despite including quite a bit of transparent space, to ensure these are aligned properly with the player game object:

[image]

This ensures the sword follows the player as he jumps by making use of the hero transition like this `transform.position = hero.transform.position;` , and though there may be issues with sprite changes I would address these later.

[image]

However, since I want to have several different equipment, and other sprites of this same sword might need a bigger dimension to look good (such as a sword attack while standing on the ground), I could either make even bigger sprites which would eventually affect performance due to transparent pixels loading, or I thought of making sprites with specific sizes:

[image]
(if this works I'd make sure to draw and put them close together instead of being separate)

And although when I prepare the animation I make sure to shift the position of the new sword to where it would be based on the player sprite on its own air attack animation (thus I had to modify this frame by frame,

[image]

The sword doesn't seem to follow the player, even when its game object still uses the script that makes use of the player's transform position:

[image]

I'm assuming something else has to be changed frame by frame, but what could it be? Is there a way to align or anchor a smaller sprite to follow the pivot of a bigger sprite?

Answer (score 1):

All rotation or changing of sprites is done relative to the sprite's Pivot Point.

[image: Pivot_Point]

When you currently swap your sprites, your sword looks like it is rotating on it's blade rather than the handle.
Change the Pivot point to the handle, and it will do most of the work.

[image: Change_Pivot_1]
[image: Change_Pivot_2]

The rest is just making sure the handle of the sword follows the character's hands.

Comment: How could I make the handle follow the player’s hand? Although this is an interesting idea, I’m not sure if it could apply in my case since each sprite is different and not a rotated version of the previous one

Comment: From what I've been able to see after some testing, it seems `transform.position = hero.transform.position;` doesn't actually update the sword game object's position on every `Update` call